# form.control.value.any_input_name in Angular Forms not taking value from array

Tags: angular

I am trying to put values entered in input fields into an array using Angular Forms when the form is submitted and for this, I have created an array containing names of all the input fields. But whenever I try to pass values of this array to form.control.value it returns an error:

> Cannot read property '0' of undefined

HTML:

```
 <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(feed)" #feed="ngForm">
   <input type="text" ngModel name="fullName" id="fullName"  #fullName="ngModel">
   <input type="email" ngModel name="email" id="email" #email="ngModel">
   <input type="tel" ngModel name="telephone" id="telephone" #telephone="ngModel">
   <input type="text" ngModel name="city" id="city" #city="ngModel">
   <textarea ngModel name="message" id="message" #message="ngModel"></textarea>
   <button type="submit" id="submit">SEND</button>
</form>
```

In App.Component.ts:

```
onSubmit(form:NgForm){
  let contact = [];
  const fieldArr = ['fullName','email','telephone','city','message'];
  for(let i=0; i < fieldArr.length; i++) {
    let holder = form.control.value.fieldArr[i];
    contact.push(holder);
  }
  console.log(contact);
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direct issue you are having I think is related to your statement that follows

```
  const fieldArr = ['fullName','email','telephone','city','message'];
  for(let i=0; i < fieldArr.length; i++) {
    let holder = form.control.value.fieldArr[i];
    contact.push(holder);
  }
```

Here you are trying to access a property named as 'fieldArr' on the 'form.control.value'.  Based on the code submitted, no such property will exist on the value.  Thus the response you are getting.

```
Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

However, I think your approach might be the larger issue.  Have you tried logging out the form.value?  It could be done in a statement like this.

```
console.log(form.value);
```

I think if you do that, you will see an object there that has all of the input values you are looking for.  It may even be already formatted as you are hoping to see it.

I have found the angular.io site to be very helpful with examples like this.  What you are working with is what they refer to as Reactive Forms.  Here is a link to their guide.  Hope it helps. https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms